# Merging Lines - up to 200ft distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, merge, snapping

I have inherited data that is in need of the lines to be in the same place. Unfortunately this is not how the data was made. I have been moving these by hand.

Is there a tool that will arbitrarily pick the center of the options and make one cohesive line here?

I have tried the snapping tool but it is not fixing lines like these.

[image]

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: I am using ArcMap

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [the help for the Integrate tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm).  Integrate allows you to collocate vertices based on distance.  Make a backup of your data first since this tool is going to alter the original geometry of your data.

This tool may not give the results you need as it may merge lines that you do not intend to merge.  Tools in ArcGIS respect selections - maybe you can improve the output from this tool by selecting only those lines from the data that you intend to integrate.  For example, maybe your data are GPS tracks along roads.  If those data have road names, do a select by attribute to select roads of the same name, then run integrate on the selections.  To repeat this step for all your data you will need to sort out iterators in ModelBuilder, have some experience with Python and arcpy, or select manually in ArcMap and run Integrate.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into this as a workflow.